# Host is not allowed to connect to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

First of all I'm acknowledging you that I am a completely newbie in this field. The `field` I'm referring to is the summation of these things:

- Accessing files on different computers or over the internet programmatically or this `PHP` + `MySQL`
- Upload some files through the internet hosted for free
- Uploading files using `FTP`
- Other common internet protocols

*(I don't know what to call to them)*

I have already uploaded some files in the free web host I chose and created a database there using **phpMyAdmin v2.11.4**

Also, I have Googled first this question before posting this here but I don't understand some rules and I need a clarification.

The exact error I get from viewing my uploaded file(index.php) is this:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/1130): Host '31.170.160.98' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/a6400350/public_html/subdomains/index.php on line 7
```

Domain name of free web host I'm using is [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com)

And my php code for connecting to host is:

```
<?php

$host = "sql10.000webhost.com"; //or "31.170.160.98"
$username = "a6400350xxxxxx";
$password = "••••••••";

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password);

?>
```

- I also check if the server is down [here](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com) **or it's just me**
- There was also no **previlege** section in `phpMyAdmin` page as other
  suggest

**Don't I have any permission to connect programmatically to this host as I am just a free user?**

**Edit**

> I'm also thinking of uploading the whole `XAMPP` in the server so I
>   could do the things I'm imagining.